# Show that $(p \leftrightarrow q) \wedge (p \to r) \vee (\neg p \to (q \wedge r))$ is not a tautology.

Tags: logic

Show that
$(p \leftrightarrow q) \wedge (p \to r) \vee (\neg p \to (q \wedge r))$
is not a tautology, using symbolic derivation  ($\wedge$ is a conjunction).
I tried using several identities to reach $((p \to q) \wedge (q \to r) \wedge (p \to r)) \vee (p \vee (q \wedge r))$ but I can't find anyway to reach the required result.

Comment: @Axoren It gets more complicated if i do that .

Comment: although it gets more complicated at first, it's easier to simplify. Ideally, you want to get it into either Disjunctive Normal Form or Conjunctive Normal Form. In either of these forms, it's easier to answer your question.

Comment: It turns out that to do it in an easy way would be using a truth table.

Comment: Is it $((p \leftrightarrow q) \wedge (p \to r)) \vee (\neg p \to (q \wedge r))$ or $(p \leftrightarrow q) \wedge ((p \to r) \vee (\neg p \to (q \wedge r)))$?